# Correctly getting size of integer array created with malloc using c

Tags: c

I have created an array using malloc with the following line of code:

```
 int* array = (int*)malloc(12*sizeof(int));
```

I attempt to get the size with:

```
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
```

This returns 2 however, not 12 (I'm aware that sizeof(array[0] is more general.)
Confusingly (for me), when I create an array using

```
int array[12]
```

the above line of code returns the correct size: 12.

Further, I'm able to fill the int* array with 12 integers without a segmentation fault, which I don't understand if the size turns out to be 2.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong / 
how to get the size of an array initialized using malloc in c?

Sorry if this is basic I looked around and couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Comment: The first `array` is not an array, but a pointer to elements of type `int`. The second one is!

Comment: There's more than likely a duplicate somewhere, but the general answer is `sizeof(array)` in the first case gives you the size of the pointer, *not* the size of the array; there's no way to determine the size of an array from just a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

No need to cast malloc().
`arr` is a pointer so in the first case you are using the

```
sizeof(arr)
```

which gives you the size of pointer not the size of the array.

In the second case you have a array

```
int arr[12];
```

Here you get the size of your array `arr` which is

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)
```